# Undefined this in ES6/Typescript Callback Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In an Ionic/Angular project, I would like to move from the ES5 syntax of referencing *this* by using a *self* variable to Arrow Functions.

However, arrow functions don't seem to allow me to access *this* inside a callback function.

Here is an example of using the arrow function for the *then* case of a Promise (Ionic's LocalStorage), which results in *this* as being undefined.

```
constructor(private storage: Storage) {
}

getItems() {
   this.storage.get('items').then((res) => {
      console.log(this);
})
```

I've even found a guide that seems to do exactly the same: [Ionic Todo List](https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-todo-app-from-scratch-with-ionic-2-video-tutorial/)

His DataService:

```
getData() {
   return this.storage.get('todos'); 
}
```

His Component:

```
  this.dataService.getData().then((todos) => {

      if(todos){
        this.items = todos;
      }
  });
```

As I've said, using a dummy variable works perfectly:

```
   getItems() {
   let self = this;

   this.storage.get('items').then((res) => {
      console.log(self);
})
```

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how arrow functions work? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is a more complete example:

My Ionic3 DataProvider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.storage.get('items');
  }
}
```

My Ionic3 HomePage:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  items = [{
    title: 'Title',
    description: 'Description'
  }];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,       
              private dataProvider: DataProvider) {

    let self = this;
    this.dataProvider.getItems()
      .then((items) => {
        # self works perfectly, but this is undefined
        console.log(self.items);
        console.log(this.items);

      if (items) {
        self.items = items;
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');
  }
}
```

Expected: this should be equal self, but is undefined

I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Your getItems function seems correct but as your constructor is empty, it's hard to guess what code you're really testing. Please build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and precisely state what you expect to see.

Comment: I've added a more complete example. I hope the problem is now a bit clearer.

Comment: Is your target es5 or es2015?  The generated es5 code for `this` is almost identical to what you've done with `self`, so I can't imagine one would be defined and one would not.  What does your generated JavaScript look like?

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Changing the target in the tsconfig file to es6 solved it. I was under the impression that it is using es6 automatically.